Is there an easy way to convert PDF to SVG maintaining CMYK colors?
We are looking for a way to programatically convert PDFs to SVGs.
What we're using at the moment is pdf2svg and it works fine, although we miss the original CMYK colors.
Is there any way to embed the original CMYKs in the SVG (in the device-cmyk field) so we can convert them back to CMYK once the SVG manipulations is done?

If the program is open source, modify it. Otherwise write your own solution.

Please reference the specific library you're using (eg.g by a github link). There are plenty of libraries with this name. device-cmyk  is currently not supported by any major browser. So I don't think you could create something like a printable cmyk SVG which would respect the device cmyk color space.

We are using this one: https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg. I know that device-cmyk is not support in browsers. We just need to know the original CMYK. That's the whole issue: we need to convert to SVG, but remember original colors.
